# What is the difference between the arrangement/layout of the Talmud pre Bomberg's printing, and the arrangement/layout of the Talmud post Bomberg?

Tags: talmud-gemara

What is the difference between the arrangement/layout of the Talmud pre Bomberg's printing, and the arrangement/layout of the Talmud post Bomberg's printing?

For example nowadays the Talmud has quite a complex layout on the page..

I have heard that in the past maybe even the gemara wasn't published with the mishna.

Comment: pre-Bomberg's printing there was no layout, since it was not printed. The manuscript Talmud would be just the mishna and gemara, with no commentaries (which would be copied separately.)

Comment: the 1516 Ein ya'akov Talmud, from Salonica -- this is the rashi for Yoma 10 http://www.geocities.ws/ffbrosends/salonica.jpg (I added the highlighting). Yes, 30 years after Bromberg, but another printed format FYI

Comment: @simyou the first printed Talmud was Soncino. The "chiddush" of Bomberg, well, at least one of his "chiddushim" was that he printed the entire Shas. I believe Soncino had printed 16 tractates before stopping for some reason.

Comment: @Harel13 23, actually (https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=38519#p=281). Actually, anyway, Soncino wasn't the first - there exist fragments of masechtos printed in Spain and Portugal in the 1480s-90s.

Comment: Do a search of Munich manuscript 95 ,and you will be able to see a talmud from the 1300s

Answer (score 5):

Manuscripts tend to be unique. Everyone can come out different. The manuscript versions didn't even have daf numbers and there was definitely no universal dafim. That is why the rishonim never mention dafim. They say things like "it says in the begining of perek xyz...". When Bomberg printed his Rashba he writes that he added the dafim in accordance with his own shas. Printing allows for uniformity. Every edition can look the same. While not every shas strictly adhered to Bomberg's page layout they all kept the same dafim and began and ended with the same words in the gemara. It is just that some printers may have put different words on different lines.
From:
Yaakov Shmuel Spiegel, “The Layout of the Talmudic Page Through the Ages,” Kovetz Etz Hayyim, vol. 28 (2017): 492-507 (Hebrew)